# InputStream Exception while downloading a file

Tags: android, download, inputstream

I am trying to download a PPT file from a server.
it's in Bytes.

but while debugging I noticed that the input stream throws an exception of FileNotFound while running.. the file does exist on the server, here's my code, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
    int count;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + SharedPref.getAuthPrefValue());
        connection.addRequestProperty("Device", BaseApplication.getCurrentDevice().getDevice().toString());
        connection.addRequestProperty("DeviceId", BaseApplication.getCurrentDevice().getDeviceId());
        connection.connect();

        int lengthOfFile = connection.getContentLength();
        Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Length of file: " + lengthOfFile);

        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
        File sdcardDest = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Availo");
        String finalDest = sdcardDest + File.separator + "Check1" + "." + "PPT";
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(finalDest);

        byte data[] = new byte[1024];

        long total = 0;

        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;
            publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lengthOfFile));
            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }

        output.flush();
        output.close();
        input.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return null;
}
```

I am using Charles on Mac (which is similar to fiddler on windows.) to see what I send and receive from the server,
The server doesn't return any error, though it shows download steps for 6-7 sec, downloading around 400 bytes and then it stops.

The Exception is thrown from the input stream line.

Thanks!

Comment: try to changing this line InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream()); to InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());

Comment: also check this example http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/use-httpurlconnection-to-download-file-from-an-http-url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I do agree with Muzikant regarding the download manager,
 `FileNotFoundException` is usually thrown when... **the file is not found** on the local device...

You need to do the following to make sure it doesnt happen

```
File dest = new File(finalDest);

try{
    File parentDest = dest.getParentFile();
    if(!parentDest.exists()){
    parentDest.mkdirs(); //make all the directory structures needed
   }

if(!dest.exists()){
    dest.createNewFile();
}


OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(dest);
//now you can use your file dest
//write data to it... 

}catch (Exception e){


}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at the [`DownloadManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) system service. it's designed specifically for what you are trying to do:

(from the documentation)

> The download manager is a system service that handles long-running
>   HTTP downloads. Clients may request that a URI be downloaded to a
>   particular destination file. The download manager will conduct the
>   download in the background, taking care of HTTP interactions and
>   retrying downloads after failures or across connectivity changes and
>   system reboots

Comment: thanks for the advice! I just finished implementing the DownloadManager, working really good! thanks!!!